# Why has God made so many poor people on earth?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

What's the point of most people being born poor? Just think about the African countries for example.

How would Judaism address why more people are born poor than rich?

Comment: This seems like part of the general question of why bad things happen to good people.

Comment: @mevaqesh I am not saying the poor are good people, I am saying why God let so many people be born poor while few are privileged

Comment: I don't understand. If they were bad people you wouldn't have a question. Only because thy are good (when they are born) do you have this question. The question doesn't seem to be related to rich people. Poos people don't suffer more being born poor, just because someone else was born rich.

Comment: @mevaqesh There are bad people born in privilege and bad people born in poverty, I am asking why the poors are way more than those with comfortable existences. Would it have spoiled some vast eternal plan if everyone had a small fortune?

Comment: Well I don't know the economics of everyone having a small fortune. Would inflation just devalue it? || I still don't understand why your frame of reference is parity. I understand that the idea of justice suggests that someone shouldn't be baselessly punished. And I understand that being born into difficult conditions could be considered a punishment. If that is the question: why some people are born in difficult conditions, I would understand the question. However, I don't understand the question of why some are born different from others; why they be the same? Divine consistency?

Comment: @mevaqesh Africa and India alone are more than two billion of people, and the vast majority there are poor people(compared to the western standards of well-being and integrity), which did not ask to come into existence in such conditions. So what's the purpose of this exactly? God has made many poor people and privileged others which did not deserve to be privileged at all, for example just think about the german aristocracy during the nazi empire. This doesn't mean that all rich people are inherently bad people, but the weight is highly disproportional.

Comment: You don't seem to be addressing my comments. Disparity is one issue. Poorness is a separate issue. Try to decide which one you are asking, and clarify that in the post.

Comment: @mevaqesh I am precisely asking why those being born poor around the world are WAY more than those being born in comfortable conditions, in the west even the poor experiences comfortable conditions so we must address this issue on a global level and redefine the real meaning of being poor. It is also a branch of disparity

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8I9pYCl9AQ

Answer (score 3):

The Gemara in [Bava Basra 10a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=10&format=pdf) addresses this question.

> תניא היה רבי מאיר אומר יש לו לבעל הדין להשיבך ולומר לך אם אלהיכם אוהב
>   עניים הוא מפני מה אינו מפרנסן אמור לו כדי שניצול אנו בהן מדינה של
>   גיהנם וזו שאלה שאל טורנוסרופוס הרשע את ר"ע אם אלהיכם אוהב עניים הוא
>   מפני מה אינו מפרנסם א"ל כדי שניצול אנו בהן מדינה של גיהנם א"ל [אדרבה]
>   זו שמחייבתן לגיהנם אמשול לך משל למה הדבר דומה למלך בשר ודם שכעס על
>   עבדו וחבשו בבית האסורין וצוה עליו שלא להאכילו ושלא להשקותו והלך אדם
>   אחד והאכילו והשקהו כששמע המלך לא כועס עליו ואתם קרוין עבדים שנאמר כי
>   לי בני ישראל עבדים אמר לו ר"ע אמשול לך משל למה הדבר דומה למלך בשר ודם
>   שכעס על בנו וחבשו בבית האסורין וצוה עליו שלא להאכילו ושלא להשקותו והלך
>   אדם אחד והאכילו והשקהו כששמע המלך לא דורון משגר לו ואנן קרוין בנים
>   דכתיב בנים אתם לה' אלהיכם אמר לו אתם קרוים בנים וקרוין עבדים בזמן שאתם
>   עושין רצונו של מקום אתם קרוין בנים ובזמן שאין אתם עושין רצונו של מקום
>   אתם קרוין עבדים ועכשיו אין אתם עושין רצונו של מקום אמר לו הרי הוא אומר
>   הלא פרוס לרעב לחמך ועניים מרודים תביא בית אימתי עניים מרודים תביא בית
>   האידנא וקאמר הלא פרוס לרעב לחמך
>
> It has been taught: R. Meir used to say: The critic [of Judaism] may
>   bring against you the argument, ‘If your God loves the poor, why does
>   he not support them?’ If so, answer him, ‘So that through them we may
>   be saved from the punishment of Gehinnom.’ This question was actually
>   put by Turnus Rufus to R. Akiba: ‘If your God loves the poor, why does
>   He not support them?’ He replied, ‘So that we may be saved through
>   them from the punishment of Gehinnom.’ ‘On the contrary,’ said the
>   other, ‘it is this which condemns you to Gehinnom. I will illustrate
>   by a parable. Suppose an earthly king was angry with his servant and
>   put him in prison and ordered that he should be given no food or
>   drink, and a man went and gave him food and drink. If the king heard,
>   would he not be angry with him? And you are called "servants", as it
>   is written, For unto me the children of Israel are servants.’ R. Akiba
>   answered him: ‘I will illustrate by another parable. Suppose an
>   earthly king was angry with his son, and put him in prison and ordered
>   that no food or drink should be given to him, and someone went and
>   gave him food and drink. If the king heard of it, would he not send
>   him a present? And we are called "sons’, as it is written, Sons are ye
>   to the Lord your God.’ He said to him: ‘You are called both sons and
>   servants. When you carry out the desires of the Omnipresent you are
>   called "sons", and when you do not carry out the desires of the
>   Omnipresent, you are called "servants" . At the present time you are
>   not carrying out the desires of the Omnipresent. R. Akiba replied:
>   ‘The Scripture says, Is it not to deal thy bread to the hungry and
>   bring the poor that are cast out to thy house. When "dost thou bring
>   the poor who are cast out to thy house"? Now; and it says [at the same
>   time], Is it not to deal thy bread to the hungry?’ ([Soncino
>   translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Baba_Bathra.pdf))

See also Tanna D'vei Eliyahu Zuta Chapter 5 in which it is stated that God searched through all the good attributes and found none better for Israel than poverty, since poverty leads one to fear of God.

ויאמר אם יהיו כולן כשירין מה אתה אומר עליהם העניים והאביונים מבקשים מים ואין ולשונם בצמא נשתה וגו'  ואומר ויוסיפו ענוים בה' שמחה [ואביוני אדם בקדוש ישראל יגילו] ואומר הנה צרפתיך ולא בכסף בחנתיך בכור עוני מלמד שחזר הקב"ה על כל מידות טובות שבעולם (לא) [ולא] מצא להן מידה טובה לישראל אלא עניות שמתוך עניות הן יריאין את ה' אין להם לחם לאכול ובגד ללבוש ושמן לסוך (יבקשו) [ובקשו] רחמים ומצאו נימצא על ידי עניות (חיו ויריאין) [היו יריאין] את ה' אין עושי חסד באין אלא מתוך עניות ואין [עושי] צדקות באין אלא מתוך עניות ואין גומלי חסדים [באין] אלא מתוך עניות ואין יראי שמים באין אלא מתוך עניות שנאמר מקים מעפר דל ומאשפות ירים אביון לא נאמר מקים ממיטתו עשיר כי לה' מצוקי ארץ ואין מצוקין אלא תלמידי חכמים שנאמר ויתקבצו עליו כל איש מצוק וגו